# javascript and jquery is not working my php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

if i have insert script events or function code within my index php file.
that is not working.

My files:

1.header php file(this file contain only css and header html)

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <title>Administrator</title>
                <!-- CSS -->
                <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <div class="main-wrapper" id="main-wrapper">
                <header class="topbar">
                    .....
                </header>

2.index.php(include header and footer)

                <?php include "templates/header.php" ?>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("p").click(function(){
                            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
                <?php include "templates/footer.php" ?>

3.footer php file(script loading and end tagcontainer,body,html)

</div>
 <footer class="center-align"><p>All Rights Reserved.</footer>
</div>
</div>
```

i have insert script file insert this place

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You dont seem to have an opening `<body>` tag. That could cause problems.

Comment: if you load jquery at the end of the document, then `$` won't be defined before jquery is loaded ... of course, your *developer tools console* would've shown that `$` is undefined or not a function, or SOMETHING - tip #1 - always load javascript libraries **before** trying to use them as javascript is not prescient

Comment: Your `<body>` tag is missing and also you isn't add jquery library in your html. Or try to do your jquery after you included your jquery

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar - I assumed `i have insert script file insert this place` meant the OP loaded libraries at the end of the document - of course that is an assumption on my part, and is probably spectacularly wrong :p

Comment: Than use your script functionality after that it will work fine thwn

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar - I like peanut butter. Do you swim?

Comment: Update your code like this `<script src="your script link"></script><script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("p").click(function(){
                            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
                        });
                    });
                </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <?php include "templates/header.php" ?>

            <p>Click on this paragraph.</p>

           <script src="jquerylink"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("p").click(function(){
                        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <?php include "templates/footer.php" ?>
```